# Ultrawingrid layout

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am working on an ultrawingrid. The grid has two columns Name & Age. The are more than 300 rows in the grid, so user needs to do lot of scrolling. I want to change the layout of the grid to display as much information as possible and with minimum scrolling.

So for example, presently it looks like

```
 Name     Age
 Sam       25
 Bob       20
 Irvin     45
 Tanya     24
 Mark      30
```

How, I intend to display it as

```
Sam   25       Bob   20       Irvin   45
Tanya 24       Mark  30
```

so essentially, in some form of matrix for which I could set up number of rows and columns and which is scroll-able vertically (and not horizonatally)

I tried to play around with CardView property http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/HTML/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBand~CardView.html and setting its MaxCardAreaCols and MaxcardAreaRows settings, however it doesn't work. I tried to follow Rowlayout property by setting up layout to ColumnLayout and that did not work either.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: I think a listview better suits your idea.

Comment: Thanks Rand. This control is already in place. I cannot change the choice of control.

Comment: Rand is correct that the ListView is a better control for this.  Is there are reason that you can't change the control you are using?  As far as using the grid, you would need multiple columns in your data source to accomplish this and then the grids sorting and filtering wouldn't work as you expect either.

Answer (score 1):

A hack that might work for you is to create a special class just for display purposes.

```
public class DisplayRow
{
    string Name1 { get; set; }
    string Age1 { get; set; }
    string Name2 { get; set; }
    string Age2 { get; set; }
    // So on...
}
```

But this complicates the logic and gets quite ugly depending on the complexity of what you're doing.

Comment: I think this sort of thing (a custom display-only data structure populated from your DataSet) is your best bet, though I would go with a temporary DataSet with columns Name1, Age1, Name2, Age2, Name3, Age3 and set that as your DataSource.